# timer for react function not starting correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to time how long a user takes to answer a question in a quiz.

The current code looks something like this

```
function Answer({ currentQuestion, submitAnswer }) {
  var start = Date.now();

  const inputsRef = useRef();
  // const [secondsRemaining, setSecondsRemaining] = useState(0)

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let nth = parseInt(e.target.dataset.nth, 10);

    if (value === "") return;

    let inputs = inputsRef.current.querySelectorAll("input");

    inputs.forEach((element) => {
      if (parseInt(element.dataset.nth, 10) === nth + 1) {
        element.focus();
        element.select();
      }
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    let finalValue = "";
    const finished =  Date.now()
    const secondsCompleted = finished - start;
    let seconds = Math.floor((secondsCompleted / 1000) % 60);

    console.log(    seconds)
    let inputs = inputsRef.current.querySelectorAll("input");
    inputs.forEach((element) => (finalValue += element.value));

    finalValue = finalValue.toUpperCase();

    submitAnswer(finalValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inputsRef.current.querySelectorAll("input")[0].focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={inputsRef}
        className="input-container flex justify-center flex-wrap"
      >
        {.... <input.../>}
....
  );
}
```

Currently the timer only begins when use inputs a value into the input form.

How can I have it start when this function renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could do something like this:**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Answer({ currentQuestion, submitAnswer }) {
  const inputsRef = useRef();
  const [secondsRemaining, setSecondsRemaining] = useState(0);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    if (!secondsRemaining) {
      setSecondsRemaining(new Date().getTime());
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const time = new Date().getTime();
    setSecondsRemaining(time - secondsRemaining);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inputsRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  console.log(secondsRemaining);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={inputsRef} onChange={handleInput}>
        <input />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Answer />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use state for the start in your component because each time there is update inside your application, it will change and it will never be the right time the user started to see the question. And you should add useEffect to check when the question changes and update the start time.
You should make it like this:

```
const [start, setStart] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    setStart(Date.now());
}, [currentQuestion])
```

Comment: Unfortunatelywhen using this approach, setStart does not fire on render for some reason

Comment: And if you set the default value of start to Date.now() ? `const [start, setStart] = useState(Date.now());`

Comment: Now the initial time works, but the handle submit does not work with setStart, not updating the value